# Printed Barcode with Barcode39 Library Not Getting Scanned

Tags: css, codeigniter, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am using Barcode39 Library in codeigniter to generate barcodes.

Below is the helper function I am using to generate the barcode.

```
function generatebarcode12($Qty,$OrderId,$OrderItemId,$ServiceCatId){
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('Barcode39');


    $ci->load->helper('upload_function');

    $configArr = array(
            'thickness' => 30,
            'resolution' => 1,
            'fontsize' => 2,
            'a1' => 'A',
            'a2' => '',
            'code' => 'code39'
    );

    $ci->load->library('barcode/barcodeclass',$configArr);

    $UploadDirConfig = uploadDirctoryConfig('barcode',$OrderId);

    makeDirectory($UploadDirConfig['main_dir_full_path']);
    makeDirectory($UploadDirConfig['sub_dir_barcode']);
    makeDirectory($UploadDirConfig['sub_child_dir_full_path']);
    $uploadpath = $UploadDirConfig['sub_child_dir_full_path'];

    for ($i=0;$i<$Qty;$i++){
        $barcode = generate_barcode_no($OrderId, $OrderItemId, $ServiceCatId, $Qty);
        $chkunique = checkbarcode_unique($barcode);
        while(!$chkunique){
            $barcode    = generate_barcode_no($OrderId, $OrderItemId, $ServiceCatId, $Qty);
            $chkunique  = checkbarcode_unique($barcode);
        }

        if($barcode){
            $filename = $barcode.'.gif';

            $bc = new Barcode39($barcode);
            // set text size
            $bc->barcode_text_size = 1;
            // set barcode bar thickness (thick bars)
            $bc->barcode_bar_thick = 2;
            // set barcode bar thickness (thin bars)
            $bc->barcode_bar_thin = 1;
            $bc->barcode_height = 50;

            if(file_exists($uploadpath.$filename)){
                $output = true;
                $output = $bc->draw($uploadpath.$filename);//Generate barcode with method2
                //$output = $ci->barcodeclass->generate($barcode,$filename,$uploadpath);//Generate barcode with method1
            }else{
                $output = $bc->draw($uploadpath.$filename);//Generate barcode with method2
                //$output = $ci->barcodeclass->generate($barcode,$filename,$uploadpath);//Generate barcode with method1
            }

            if($output){


                $data = array();
                $data['OrderId']        = $OrderId;
                $data['OrderItemId']    = $OrderItemId;
                $data['Code']           = $barcode;
                $data['ImageName']      = $filename;
                $data['Status']         = 'InProgress';
                $data['CreatedAt']      = get_curr_datetime();
                $data['CreatedBy']      = get_login_user_id();
                grid_add_data($data,TBL_BARCODE);
            }
        }
    }

    return $UploadDirConfig;
}
```

I am rotating generated barcode image by 90 degree using below css code:

```
#rotate90deg {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

I am using TSC TTP-244 Plus printer to print barcodes and Motorola Scanner to scan the barcodes.

The main problem is that out of 12 barcodes, only around 2 to 3 barcodes are getting scanned.

Please help me with this.

@Swinders: Actually it is not possible to share you the image of the barcode that did not scan, but I am attaching a sample barcode image which we are printing for scanning.

[image]

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Can you supply examples of the codes that do and do not scan?

Comment: Hi Swinders, the codes that I am scanning are normal integers like 1-1-1 or 15-22-11. I also want to inform that when I changed my configuration array, increased the thickness of the barcodes, they are getting scanned. But i really want to know what the issue might be?

Comment: Would you be able to show the example codes that don't scan as images?

Comment: There are two codes for example 00034-53-5 and 00034-52-9, out of the two codes 00034-53-5 is getting scanned properly and the code is not getting scanned.

Comment: Without seeing the codes that are causing you an issue it is difficult to help further. The images you have shown appear to be coded correctly so I would imagine basic barcode generation is working. Rotating by 90 degrees is a trivial matter. As you are able to read some of the codes the scanner must at least be able to decode the Code39 codes. Assuming the printing is completed smoothly the only remaining part to look at is that no scaling is performed which can hide a bar. Are the bars well defined with no grey or dithered edges?

Answer (score 0):

As you are rotating the generated barcode image by 90 degrees you should check the printer is printing the code correctly.

I have see that sometimes a linear code (such as Code39) when printed down the label will be slightly squashed in places, possibly due to the media not feeding freely. If the thickness of the bars are too small the media feed can be more critical.

Generally printing linear (1D) codes appears to be more reliable when printed across the label.

Comment: No, there is no issue in printing the barcodes. All the barcodes are getting printed properly.

Comment: @SwapnilPunekar Do the codes print and scan correctly when printed horizontally?

Comment: Actually the printer that I am has a very narrow strip because of which it is not possible to print them horizontally. That's why I am rotating them before printing.

Comment: Can you share an image of the codes that don't scan?

Comment: I have attached the image in the question. I hope that it helps!